# Can I upgrade my 2007 front suspension?

Tags: mountain-bike, maintenance, shocks

I just bought a 2007 Trek Fuel EX5 used but the front suspension dial is cracked and makes it difficult to change the give. The current forks that are on there are RockShock Tora's. Would it be possible to change this out knowing the tire and tread size?

Edit: Thanks for the input guys. You make a good point Matt, I paid $350 for the bike so it might not be worth it, but the front suspension is at nearly full give so I’m a bit worried I’ll constantly bottom out.

Knowing that I’m not eligible for the upgrade program, how much do you guys think it would cost to buy the parts used/new and which one of those is the best option?

Comment: Possible -yes, worth it - unlikely.  If the forks are otherwise working fine, the cost of the upgrade could exceed the cost of the bike. Probably better to save the money for a later upgrade of the bike and set the Tora's to an all round setting.

Comment: A photo would be nice. It is possible that the dial is available as spare part.

Comment: Have you somehow created a second account ?  Looks like users Noah and Noaheh are the same person ?  Instead of replying in an answer, either edit more info into your question, or possibly use a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **Yes easy**.

My recommended process:

If you are the original owner of the bike check out SR Suntour's upgrade program.

https://www.srsuntour.us/pages/upgrade

The [RAIDON XC-LO-R 26](https://www.srsuntour.us/products/raidon-xc-lo-r?variant=27529038787) with a straight steerer would be a really good fork for that bike at $199 down from $299 with the deal.

If that isn't appealing you'll want anything that has support for a **26" wheel**, **100mm of travel**, and a **straight 1 1/8" steerer**. I doubt you'll be able to fit anything over a 2.3-2.4" tire in there.

Note: For the fork from SR Suntour I mentioned, it has a 160mm flat mount support for brakes, so you'll probably have to upgrade your front rotor to a larger size as well.

Comment: OP is not original owner - he states he "just bought" the 2007 model bike so in not eligible for the upgrade program